PyMongo - Import extended json file into MongoDB
Is it possible to import an extended JSON file to MongoDB using Python's pymongo?
For instance, the JSON file to import has multiple documents with "$date", for instance:
[{"t": {"$date": "2024-06-10",...}}, {"t": {"$date": "2024-06-11", ...}}]

At the moment I have the following which is successful, though this reads the import as JSON data and loses the MongoDB type information. Is there anyway of preserving this information, via bson.json_util ?
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(db_connection)
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    # If JSON contains multiple documents, insert_many is used
    # otherwise insert_one is used for a single document
    if isinstance(data, list):
        client[db_name][collection_name].insert_many(data)
    else:
        client[db_name][collection_name].insert_one(data)

Thanks
